# TCPListener server to discover clients on a network

Tags: f#, networking, server, tcp, immutability

I am currently writing a program to sync files (music, photos, etc) from my PC to an Android device. In order to do this, I have 2 application: one that is running on my PC, and one that shall be running on the Android device. When the Android app will open, it will try to connect to a specified IP:port on the PC application, which has a server just listening for requests in order to show the clients in a WPF list style view. This server is written in F#.

Here is the server implementation I have come up with:

```
type TCPListenerServer(discoveryPort:int) =
    let server = new TcpListener (IPAddress.Loopback, discoveryPort)

    let activeConnections = new List<TcpClient>()

    let serverLoop () =
        let rec loop (pendingConnection:Task<TcpClient>) = async {            
            let newPendingConnection, client =
                match pendingConnection.Status with
                | TaskStatus.Created | TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation | TaskStatus.WaitingToRun | TaskStatus.Running  ->
                    (None, None)
                | TaskStatus.Faulted | TaskStatus.Canceled ->
                    raise (new System.NotImplementedException())
                | TaskStatus.RanToCompletion ->
                    let connectionTask = server.AcceptTcpClientAsync ()
                    (Some connectionTask, Some pendingConnection.Result)
                | _ -> 
                    raise (new System.NotImplementedException())

            // Add the new client to the list
            Option.iter (fun c -> activeConnections.Add c) client

            // Switch the new pending connection if there is one
            let connectionAttempt = defaultArg newPendingConnection pendingConnection

            Async.Sleep 1000 |> Async.RunSynchronously
            return! loop connectionAttempt
        }

        try
            server.Start ()

            let connectionTask = server.AcceptTcpClientAsync ()

            loop connectionTask
        finally
            server.Stop ()

    member x.Start () =
        serverLoop () |> Async.Start

    member x.Stop () =
        server.Stop ()

    member x.ActiveConnections =
        activeConnections
```

I wanted to know if my implementation was acceptable. I am unsure what is best: using a .NET `List`, or using a mutable variable that holds an F# list for `activeConnections`.

Also, usually I would keep the state of my object encapsulated in the `serverLoop` and just passing the updated list to each iteration, but doing this I cannot expose it so that I may have access to it from the outside (to bind on it in my WPF for example). Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider altering `member x.ActiveConnections` for the reasons I mention on the answer here: [Create database connection and run the insert, delete, update queries class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/137879/create-database-connection-and-run-the-insert-delete-update-queries-class/138036#138036)

Basically, consumers of your class **can** actually modify the `ActiveConnections` list (call `.Remove`, etc.), so you should find a way to eliminate that.

In F#, I would probably do the following:

```
member x.ActiveConnections = activeConnections.ToArray()
```

Or as Dan Lyons stated in comments:

```
member x.ActiveConnections = activeConnections.AsReadOnly()
```

This guarantees that you are exposing a non-modifiable copy of the list to the consumer of your class. You could optionally `open System.Linq` and use:

```
member x.ActiveConnections = activeConnections.ToArray().AsEnumerable()
```

Both of these have the same effect: the internal `List<T>` isn't able to be modified.

---

I also noticed you use `x.` as the prefix for all your `member` declarations, I'm not sure what the standard is (quick google pulled nothing) but I always try to use `member this.Name` for public-facing members, to remind myself that they're part of the same object. (F# doesn't seem to care much, but it still *feels* right.)

Comment: You could also use [`List<T>.AsReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75(v=vs.110).aspx), which returns a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` object.

Comment: @DanLyons Added that example as well.