# Database abstraction layer for multiple providers

Tags: c#, database, generics, framework, fluent-interface

There's been a lot of questions lately about database provider and repository design especially without entity framework or alike.

I thought I try myself to create a reusable *framework* for this kind of stuff. So let's begin ;-)

*TL;DR - There's an example at the bottom*

---

**Core**

The main part of the framework is the `DbProvider` class with a corresponding interface. It encapsulates the most repetitive common tasks like managing a connection, executing queries and adding parameters. There is one thing that this early version lacks namely sql injection protection. The parameters need to be sanitized later.

I used generics to make it strongly typed and avoid magic strings later (like table or column names). With this design it supports each provider's own data types.

```
public interface IDbProvider
{
    int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, Action<ParameterBuilder> parameters = null);
    IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> ExecuteReader(
        string sql, 
        Action<ParameterBuilder> parameters = null);
}

public abstract class DbProvider<TConnection, TCommand, TData> : IDbProvider
    where TConnection : DbConnection
    where TCommand : DbCommand
{
    private readonly DbProviderFactory _dbProviderFactory;

    protected DbProvider(
        string providerInvariantName, 
        string connectionString, 
        Action<DbConfigurationBuilder<TData>> dbConfiguration)
    {
        _dbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerInvariantName);
        var dbConfigurationBuilder = new DbConfigurationBuilder<TData>(connectionString);
        dbConfiguration(dbConfigurationBuilder);
        DbConfiguration = dbConfigurationBuilder.Build();
    }

    public DbConfiguration<TData> DbConfiguration { get; }

    public abstract string ParameterPrefix { get; }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, Action<ParameterBuilder> parameters = null)
    {
        var parameterBuilder = new ParameterBuilder();
        parameters?.Invoke(parameterBuilder);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sql))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Value may not be null or whitespace", "sql");
        }

        using (var connection = _dbProviderFactory.CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = DbConfiguration.ConnectionString;
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                AddParameters((TCommand)command, parameterBuilder.Tables);
                return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> ExecuteReader(
        string sql, 
        Action<ParameterBuilder> parameters = null)
    {
        var parameterBuilder = new ParameterBuilder();
        parameters?.Invoke(parameterBuilder);

        using (var connection = _dbProviderFactory.CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = DbConfiguration.ConnectionString;
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = sql;
                AddParameters((TCommand)command, parameterBuilder.Tables);
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                        .Select(reader.GetName).ToList();

                    var result = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        result.Add(columns.ToDictionary(c => c, c => reader[c]));
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract void AddParameters(
        TCommand command, 
        IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>> parameters);
}
```

---

**SqlClientProvider**

This is an example of a sql-client-provider. It overrides the `AddParameters` method to use its own types and the parameter prefix.

```
public class SqlClientProvider : DbProvider<SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDbType>
{
    public SqlClientProvider(
        string connectionString, 
        Action<DbConfigurationBuilder<SqlDbType>> dbConfiguration)
        : base("System.Data.SqlClient", connectionString, dbConfiguration)
    { }

    public override string ParameterPrefix => "@";

    protected override void AddParameters(
        SqlCommand command, 
        IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>> parameters)
    {
        foreach (var table in parameters)
        {
            foreach (var column in table.Value)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(
                    $"{ParameterPrefix}{column.Key}",
                    DbConfiguration.TableConfigurations[table.Key].ColumnConfigurations[column.Key].DataType,
                    DbConfiguration.TableConfigurations[table.Key].ColumnConfigurations[column.Key].Length
                ).Value = column.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Helpers**

If someone would like to test it I include here the whole set of supporting types that make the entire thing work and provide a strongly typed fluent api.

I will not comment on this. They are just a bunch of builders to make it easier to use and to eliminate magic strings.

---

*Database configuration*

```
public class DbConfiguration<TData>
{
    public DbConfiguration(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
        TableConfigurations = new Dictionary<string, TableConfiguration<TData>>();
    }
    public string ConnectionString { get; }
    public string SchemaName { get; internal set; }
    public Dictionary<string, TableConfiguration<TData>> TableConfigurations { get; }
}

public class TableConfiguration<TData>
{
    public TableConfiguration()
    {
        ColumnConfigurations = new Dictionary<string, ColumnConfiguration<TData>>();
    }
    public Dictionary<string, ColumnConfiguration<TData>> ColumnConfigurations { get; }

}

public class ColumnConfiguration<TDataType>
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public TDataType DataType { get; set; }
}
```

---

*Database configuration builders*

```
public class DbConfigurationBuilder<TData>
{
    private readonly DbConfiguration<TData> _dbConfiguration;

    public DbConfigurationBuilder(string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        _dbConfiguration = new DbConfiguration<TData>(nameOrConnectionString);
    }

    public DbConfigurationBuilder<TData> SchemaName(string schemaName)
    {
        _dbConfiguration.SchemaName = schemaName;
        return this;
    }

    public DbConfigurationBuilder<TData> Table<TTable>(Action<TableConfiguraitonBuilder<TTable, TData>> tableConfiguration)
    {
        var tableConfigurationBuilder = new TableConfiguraitonBuilder<TTable, TData>();
        tableConfiguration(tableConfigurationBuilder);
        _dbConfiguration.TableConfigurations[tableConfigurationBuilder.Name] = tableConfigurationBuilder.TableConfiguraion;
        return this;
    }

    public DbConfiguration<TData> Build() => _dbConfiguration;
}

public class TableConfiguraitonBuilder<TTable, TData>
{
    private readonly TableConfiguration<TData> _tableConfiguration;

    public TableConfiguraitonBuilder()
    {
        _tableConfiguration = new TableConfiguration<TData>();
    }

    public TableConfiguraitonBuilder<TTable, TData> Column<TColumn>(
        Expression<Func<TTable, TColumn>> expression,
        Action<ColumnConfigurationBuilder<TData>> columnConfiguration)
    {
        var columnConfigurationBuilder = new ColumnConfigurationBuilder<TData>();
        columnConfiguration(columnConfigurationBuilder);
        _tableConfiguration.ColumnConfigurations[ExpressionHelper.GetMemberName(expression)] = columnConfigurationBuilder.ColumnConfiguration;
        return this;
    }

    internal string Name => typeof(TTable).Name;

    internal TableConfiguration<TData> TableConfiguraion => _tableConfiguration;
}

public class ColumnConfigurationBuilder<TData>
{
    private readonly ColumnConfiguration<TData> _columnConfiguration;

    public ColumnConfigurationBuilder()
    {
        _columnConfiguration = new ColumnConfiguration<TData>();
    }

    public ColumnConfigurationBuilder<TData> HasLength(int length)
    {
        _columnConfiguration.Length = length;
        return this;
    }

    public ColumnConfigurationBuilder<TData> HasDataType(TData dataType)
    {
        _columnConfiguration.DataType = dataType;
        return this;
    }

    internal ColumnConfiguration<TData> ColumnConfiguration => _columnConfiguration;
}

static class ExpressionHelper
{
    public static string GetMemberName<T, P>(Expression<Func<T, P>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression != null)
        {
            return memberExpression.Member.Name;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid expression type.", nameof(expression));
    }
}
```

---

*Parameter builders*

```
public class ParameterBuilder
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>> _tables;

    public ParameterBuilder()
    {
        _tables = new Dictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>>();
    }

    internal IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>> Tables => _tables;

    public ParameterBuilder Table<TTable>(Action<TableBuilder<TTable>> table)
    {
        var tableBuilder = new TableBuilder<TTable>();
        table(tableBuilder);
        _tables[typeof(TTable).Name] = tableBuilder.Columns;
        return this;
    }
}

public class TableBuilder<TTable>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _columns;

    public TableBuilder()
    {
        _columns = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    internal IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> Columns => _columns;

    public TableBuilder<TTable> Column<TColumn>(Expression<Func<TTable, TColumn>> expression, object value)
    {
        _columns[ExpressionHelper.GetMemberName(expression)] = value;
        return this;
    }
}
```

---

**Example & Usage**

*Test models*

```
public class Setting
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

*Test repository*

This repository creates a sql-client-provider and initializes the tables and columns with types and lengths.

It also provides a test method for selecting settings `GetValues` that uses the framework.

```
public class FooRepository
{
    private readonly IDbProvider _dbProvider;

    public FooRepository(IDbProvider dbProvider)
    {
        _dbProvider = dbProvider;
    }

    public static FooRepository CreateWithSqlClient(string connectionString)
    {
        return new FooRepository(new SqlClientProvider(connectionString, b =>
        {
            // These settings are used when adding parameters.
            b.Table<Setting>(t =>
            {
                t.Column(c => c.Name, c => c.HasLength(200).HasDataType(SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                t.Column(c => c.Value, c => c.HasLength(-1).HasDataType(SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            });
            b.Table<User>(t =>
            {
                t.Column(c => c.Id, c => c.HasDataType(SqlDbType.Int));
                t.Column(c => c.Login, c => c.HasLength(30).HasDataType(SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                t.Column(c => c.Password, c => c.HasLength(30).HasDataType(SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            });
        }));
    }

    public List<string> GetValues(string name)
    {
        return _dbProvider.ExecuteReader(
            "select [value] from [setting] where [name] = @name",
            p => p.Table<Setting>(t => t.Column(s => s.Name, name)) // needs caching
        )
        .Select(r => r.Values.First())
        .Cast<string>()
        .ToList();
    }
}
```

Using the repository:

```
var fooRepo = FooRepository.CreateWithSqlClient(connectionString);
var results = fooRepo.GetValues("Foo").Dump();
```

Comment: I love your questions. I'm still trying to finish reviewing your  Custom string formatters. Will be coming shortly for this one **wink**

Comment: @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo thx ;-) I'm trying to make them as short as I can but it's not easy. This is the least working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `DbProvider<TConnection, TCommand, TData>`

In the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method you are doing stuff before you check the passed in parameter `sql` for validness. You should place the validation at the top of the method.

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, Action<ParameterBuilder> parameters = null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sql))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Value may not be null or whitespace", "sql");
    }
```

If the connection couldn't be opened because the passed connectionstring is wrong or the DBMS couldn't be reached, the work which may be done by the passed in `Action<ParameterBuilder> parameters` will be unnecessary/lost. So placing this inside the `using` block may be better like so

```
    using (var connection = _dbProviderFactory.CreateConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = DbConfiguration.ConnectionString;
        connection.Open();
    
        var parameterBuilder = new ParameterBuilder();
        parameters?.Invoke(parameterBuilder);

        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            AddParameters((TCommand)command, parameterBuilder.Tables);
            return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Right now this method takes two parameters, hence having a third which takes a `CommandType` enum wouldn't hurt and you wouldn't need to change this if a stored procedure should be used.

This results in

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, CommendType commandType, Action<ParameterBuilder> parameters = null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sql))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Value may not be null or whitespace", "sql");
    }

    using (var connection = _dbProviderFactory.CreateConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = DbConfiguration.ConnectionString;
        connection.Open();

        var parameterBuilder = new ParameterBuilder();
        parameters?.Invoke(parameterBuilder);

        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = commandType;
            AddParameters((TCommand)command, parameterBuilder.Tables);
            return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

---

In the `ExecuteReader()` method you don't check the validness of the `sql` parameter. You really should do this. The mentioned points about the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method apply to this method as well.

Comment: I purposely removed the `CommandType` from the signature because I'm going to write a second method called `ExecuteStoredProcedure`. I agree with the rest ;-) For sql validation I will add a sanitizer where you can write the query like `select [name] from {schema}.{table} where [name] = @name` where the `{schema}` and `{table}` will be passed via parameters and sanitized internally then injected into to the string, this should work for other names too.

Comment: `because I'm going to write a second method called ExecuteStoredProced‌​ure` ... and then you will write a `ExecuteReaderStoredProcedure` ? Both will lead to some code duplication.

Comment: not necessarily, I can have a third one that requires the command-type parameter but me as a user wouldn't like to specify it everytime... I'll probably go with `ExecuteQuery` & `ExecuteStoredProcedure` and leave the parameter as an internal matter for the third method `ExecuteReader`... tough decisions ;-)

Comment: `but me as a user wouldn't like to specify it everytime` this is an argument I can understand. Usually I would suggest having the `CommandType` as an optional parameter, but having two optional parameters for one method just smells.

Comment: I aborted the project... and I must say it was stupid :-P although a nice exercise and I've learned a few things but it's practically rewriting entity framework. We can as well create code-first models, apply the appropriate attributes and [Execute a Parameterized Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). If you don't use EF it means the project is so tiny that for the two or three queries it's not worth to use EF and you write ad-hoc sql or it's so large that you use EF anyway.